# iOS Can't change back button image

Tags: ios, image, button, resizable

I'm trying to change the back button image using a resizable image of just a 1x1 pixel (I just want to change the color of it basically and remove the tint). The code I'm using is the following:

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But for some reason, the button seems like it is only allowing a 1 pixel line to be show:
[image]

You can see a sliver of the text of the title of the previous view.

Is there any way to just change the color of the back button and remove the tint so it's a solid color without having to create a new barButtonItem and remove the one already there?

Comment: You don't need to make a resizable image in this case.  The image should stretch by default (the only way to stretch a 1x1 image is to repeat its pixels)

Comment: It yields the same result using a non-resizable vs resizable image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019914/setting-a-custom-image-for-a-back-button-on-uinavigationbar

Comment: In my question I asked for a way to do it without creating a new barButtonItem.