# Swift Custom NavBar Back Button Image and Text

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I need to customise the look of a back button in a Swift project.

Here's what I have:
[image: Default Back Button]

Here's what I want:
[image: Custom Back Button]

I've tried creating my own UIBarButtonItem but I can't figure out how to get the image to be beside the text, rather than as a background or a replacement for the text.

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Custom", style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil    )
//backButton.image = UIImage(named: "imageName") //Replaces title
backButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "imageName"), forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default) // Stretches image
navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(backButton, animated: false)
```

Comment: @Randy You mean make a UIView and add a Label and ImageView and set that?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
let yourBackImage = UIImage(named: "back_button_image")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = yourBackImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = yourBackImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Custom"
```

Your image will only have one color though

Comment: Mostly worked, the title of the button didn't change.



    let yourBackImage = UIImage(named: "back_button_image")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = yourBackImage                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = yourBackImage
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Custom"

Comment: My back button ends up in the center of the screen? Any thoughts?

Comment: @lusus_vir Did you end up fixing this issue? I'm seeing the same result.

Comment: I there, if I use this code, this will change every back icon for the controllers that belongs to the same navigation controller, so how can I manage this behavior to only change the back button image in one controller in the same navigation controller? I try to put in a buffer the original content of self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage, but its null

Comment: I've missed "backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage". Thank you, you saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 44):

> **Note**: Please remember that the back button belongs to the the source ViewController and not to the destination ViewController. Thus, the modification needs to be done in the source VC, which is reflected to all the view in the navigation controller

Code Snippet:

```
let backImage = UIImage(named: "icon-back")

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage

/*** If needed Assign Title Here ***/
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Comment: it works, BUT, how to set the image frame. Just with this code the whole image goes out of frame.

Comment: @Annjawn image can be corrected this way: UIImage(named: "icon-back")?.stretchableImage(withLeftCapWidth: 15, topCapHeight: 30), as shown in Idan's answer below

Comment: Didn't remove the text also :(

Answer (score 33):

swift 4

In my case, I needed to have only the image of the button, without any text. I hope this will be useful to someone.

```
let imgBackArrow = UIImage(named: "back_arrow_32")

navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = imgBackArrow
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = imgBackArrow

navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
```

For iOS 12 you can do

```
func setNavigationBar() {

    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:false)

    //your custom view for back image with custom size
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20))

    if let imgBackArrow = UIImage(named: "icn_back_arrow") {
        imageView.image = imgBackArrow
    }
    view.addSubview(imageView)

    let backTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(backToMain))
    view?.addGestureRecognizer(backTap)

    let leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view ?? UIView())
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem
}

@objc func backToMain() {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Didn't remove the text on iOS12

Comment: The ios 12 method ruins the interactive  swipe to dismiss

Answer (score 13):

For setting custom back bar button and remove text from back bar button,
FROM STORYBOARD only, without any coding.

---

[image: For setting custom back button and remove text from back button]

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: The method is invalid ,cannot make it happen

Answer (score 11):

For the back button image:

- By this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/108766/uiappearance-tutorial): (but didn't work for me)

  ```
  UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "imageName")
  ```
- But this [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019914/setting-a-custom-image-for-a-back-button-on-uinavigationbar#): (worked for me)

  ```
  var backButtonImage = UIImage(named: "back-button-image")
  backButtonImage = backButtonImage?.stretchableImage(withLeftCapWidth: 15, topCapHeight: 30)
  UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backButtonImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
  ```

And for the font, assuming you want the font to match for the whole navigation bar:(currently in use)

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 22) {
  UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
}
```

Comment: Also add `UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "imageName")`, and it will work.

Answer (score 11):

Having a button in Navigation Bar with Image AND Text is quite hard. Especially after they have introduced a new headache with UIBarButtonItem position in iOS 11: [iOS 11 - UIBarButtonItem horizontal position](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80075)

You can make either button with image or a button with text, but not a button with both of those. I even tried two UIBarButtonItems together, one with image and other with text - it still doesn't look good at all and their UIStackView can't be easily accessed for modification.

Unexpectedly I found a plain simple solution:

1) design the button as view in Interface Builder. In my case it is inside target UIViewController and accessible via IBOutlet for simplicity

2) set Leading Space constraint for the image to be negative, you might also want to set view's background color to .clear.

[image]

3) use it:

```
@IBOutlet var backButtonView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.backButtonView)
    self.backButtonView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true // if you set more than you'll get "Unable to simultaneously..."
    self.backButtonView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75).isActive = true
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
}
```

That's it. No need to use the trick with negative spacer for iOS 10 or the trick with imageInsets for iOS 11 (which works only if you have image and doesn't work for image+text, BTW).

[image]

Comment: In my case arrow hit area is working a bit strange (only the right part can be touched). And also you have 2 separate buttons so it doesn't work the same, it only look the same.

Answer (score 10):

I have tried all the above and all make the custom image without changing the text
The only one worked for me is from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30110190/1565971)

```
let backBTN = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Back"), 
                              style: .plain, 
                              target: navigationController, 
                              action: #selector(UINavigationController.popViewController(animated:)))
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBTN
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
```

Comment: This is great, because this way you can set a custom selector as well to intercept the tap. Brilliant :-)

Answer (score 6):

I know it was answered. Here you can set title, image and target.

```
    let view = UIView()
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "backArrow_theme"), for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Back to workflow", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onBackButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: -10)
    button.sizeToFit()
    view.addSubview(button)
    view.frame = button.bounds
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
```

Comment: In my case, I dont need text for backbutton. Just replacing the text with blank space, didn't fixed the issue completely. Back button is still blue. I have used the following code to get the desired color. 

        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black

Comment: Perfect! Much more flexible like this.

Answer (score 5):

swift 3

```
    extension UIViewController {

        func setBackButton(){
            let yourBackImage = UIImage(named: "backbutton")
            navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = yourBackImage
            navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = yourBackImage
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on iOS 13 using swift 5. Just hide the original back button and add a new navigation left bar button item with an action.

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backBtn"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(back(sender:)))

@objc func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:true)
}
```

Comment: This is simple and works, but not perfect. The leftBarButtonItem will be a bit to the right of the back buttons original position. If this is acceptable, then go ahead and use it.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the backButton with a custom rightBarButtonItem

```
let backImage = UIImage(named: "BackBtn")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: backImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(popnav))

    @objc func popnav() {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> iOS13 And Later, Try to use `UINavigationBarAppearance`

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
// set back image
appearance.setBackIndicatorImage(UIImage(named: "back_icon"), transitionMaskImage: UIImage(named: "back_icon"))

// set appearance to one NavigationController
let navVC = UINavigationController()
navVC.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
navVC.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance

// or you can config for all navigation bar
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

> back title base on you `Viewcontroller`

```
viewController.navigationItem.backButtonTitle = "your back title"
```

Comment: This works. You can easily change the back button image without loosing its properties. Note:- If you want white nav bar , only apply appearance to navigationBar.standapperance

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2 
Add this functions `ViewController`

```
func addNavigationBarButton(imageName:String,direction:direction){
    var image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    switch direction {
    case .left:
       self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style:.plain, target: nil, action: #selector(goBack))
    case .right:
       self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style:.plain, target: nil, action: #selector(goBack))
    }
}

@objc func goBack() {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

enum direction {
    case right
    case left
}
```

Using you should use here

> viewDidLoad()

```
addNavigationBarButton(imageName: "ic_back", direction:.left)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone need to change all `Back` buttons **color** or **font** with **Swift5**. `UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = .red`

Add this to **AppDelegate.swift** file.

```
import UIKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.        
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: .red,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "font_name", size: 14)!
    ], for: .normal)

    return true
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let rectInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -1, bottom: 0, right: 0)
let backButton = Asset.Assets.backArrow.image.withAlignmentRectInsets(rectInsets)
    
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
// if you need to hide the back button text
appearance.backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]
// set custom back button image
appearance.setBackIndicatorImage(backButton, transitionMaskImage: backButton)
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the navigation controller`s **standardAppearance** or **scrollEdgeAppearance** will reset your custom backIndicatorImage and backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage

```swift
let backImage = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left.circle.fill")
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage

// this will cause the backIndicatorImage to be reset
let standardAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
navigationController?.standardAppearance = standardAppearance
```

To change the backIndicatorImage in conjunction with `UINavigationBarAppearance` you will need to set the backImage using this:

```swift
navigationController?.standardAppearance.setBackIndicatorImage(backImage, transitionMaskImage: backImage)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change it globally in the **AppDelegate** with the following code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "custom-back")
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "custom-back")
```