# setting a UIBarButtonItem to backBarButtonItem with an action, does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

When I assign the following UIBarButtonItem to `backBarButtonItem` I get a button with the title I assigned, but the action is never called.
Using `leftBarButtonItem` instead, will add a button and the action will be called. What is overriding my action? Can I do something about it?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back",
                                       style: .plain,
                                       target: self,
                                       action: #selector(backNavigationClick))
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
    }

    @objc func backNavigationClick() {
        print("back clicked")
    }
```

Comment: check your base class if any there might be something code that overides the assignment

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37554775/7084910

Answer (score -1):

if you use it in this way you can customize the button.

You need to replace this code
`navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem` 
to 
`navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem`

and add this code on backNavigationClick()

```
@objc func backNavigationClick() {
    print("back clicked")
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) ***
}
```

Comment: as I mentioned in the question, im aware it can be done using leftBarButtonItem, the problem with that is that you lose the default back arrow image. replacing it with a custom image is not what I want.

Comment: if you change only back button title, use this code: 
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Anything Else" or look this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44919649/8367837