# Use `navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal` with a custom back button image

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

For an iOS 14+ app I'd like to use `navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal` to hide the back button title, while still having the title available in the back button's long-press menu. Which works.. however I also want to change the back button image, to replace the default chevron.

But no matter what I try, I can't seem to find a solution that shows a custom back button image without a title, while also not showing a blank space in the back button's long-press menu, and not breaking the slide-to-go-back-gesture.

Anyone tried something similar, and succeeded?

So in the first view controller I show a title:

[image]

And then in the pushed view controller I want to show a custom back button image WITHOUT the "one" title (as seen below), and still have the long-press menu say "one" instead of a blank space.

[image]

This mostly gets me there actually, except that it breaks the gesture to slide to go back:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let backImage = UIImage(named: "backImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
  navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage
  navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage

  navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
}
```

Update: actually it only seems to break on the simulator, it's all fine on an actual device. I now have a minimal project setup where it all works, now to find out why it doesn't work in my actual big project!

Comment: Have your tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508911/3585796)? works fine to me

Comment: Setting a custom image is not a problem, but I can't get it to work in combination with `navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal` so that I don't get a back button title, but also don't get a blank space in the back button's long press menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured out all the problems I was having.

Basically, this code works just fine:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let backImage = UIImage(named: "backImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
  navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage
  navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage

  navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
}
```

But I was having problems with the swipe back gesture not working anymore. Turns out, that's a simulator bug, works fine on device. Then there was the problems that the custom back button image didn't actually show up in my view, because of this:

```swift
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.backgroundColor = .pageBackground
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.abbey]
appearance.shadowColor = .clear

navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
```

As soon as you set a custom appearance, that completely wipes away the custom back button image. Simple fix, just set these things directly on the navigationBar without involving the appearance.

And now it all works!

Answer (score 0):

To set the image, you can use:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = yourBackImage
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = yourBackImage
```

Let's say you have navigation from `AVC` to `BVC`.

If you want to disable the long press menu, you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64386528/3585796).

If you want the long press menu to work with the correct titles, you need to set `navigationItem.title` for your `AVC` to the right value, and `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` should be `nil`(it's the default value) for `BVC`.

If you don't want to display the title in your `AVC`, you can hide it with `titleView`:

```
navigationItem.title = "title for long press navigation menu"
navigationItem.titleView = UIView()
```